# Output sound over USB and into a computer (no 3.5mm jack)

Tags: usb, audio, output

I am trying to make a soundboard for my computer using my raspberry pi and a touchscreen. In order to mix the pi's sound out with my mic, I need it as a separate input to my computer (my mic uses the 3.5mm jack already).

How could I make my pi look like a USB microphone to my computer (preferably without any extra hardware)?

Comment: which model raspberry pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wanna configure your Rpi as a USB audio gadget. I have never done this, yet. However, you can have a look [here](https://blog.gbaman.info/?p=699) (pay close attention to the *Raspberry Pi Zero OTG Mode* insert). In this case, you wanna configure your Rpi to use the g_audio module and turn it into a USB audio gadget for use on your computer. You will do this by editing the /boot/config.txt and /boot/cmdline.txt files using a text editor of your choice. For the /boot/config.txt file, you need to add *dtoverlay=dwc2* on a new line. For the /boot/cmdline.txt file, add *modules-load=dwc2,g_ether* after *rootwait* and it will something like shown below. Since I haven't done this as of this writing, I can't confirm this will work or not. So, you are advised to backup both your /boot/config.txt and /boot/cmdline.txt files in case this approach does not work.

> dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1
>   root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes
>   rootwait modules-load=dwc2,g_audio

Answer (score 0):

You could easily find a small USB sound card with an audio in for under $10. That would enable you to connect the RPi to your PC via the jack connector.

If you have an RPi zero, using `g_audio` is also possible. Once two devices are connected, you will have a virtual sound card on both your RPi and the PC, and whatever you play on the RPi side will be streamed to the PC side and vice versa. It's a more delicate setup though, because any connectivity / playback problems will likely freeze the player on RPi, PC or both, while the jack connection can easily survive a short interruption.